# Disable Error Notices when set_error_handler() Set

Tags: php, error-handling, mpdf

I have a custom `set_error_handler()` set and I'm using mPDF which keeps giving me errors.

My Custom Error Handler:

```
function error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars) { 
$email = " 
    <p>An error (".$number.") occurred on line  
    <strong>".$line."</strong> and in the <strong>file: $file.</strong>  
    <p> ".$message." </p>";
$email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars, 1) . "</pre>";      
$headers = 'From: '.ADMIN_EMAIL.'\r\n';
$headers .= "Subject: Error from ".SITE_NAME."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Email the error to the webmaster  
error_log($email, 1, ERROR_EMAIL, $headers);  
// Make sure that you decide how to respond to errors (on the user's side)  
// Either echo an error message, or kill the entire project. Up to you...  
// The code below ensures that we only "die" if the error was more than  
// just a NOTICE.   
if ( ($number !== E_NOTICE) && ($number < 2048) ) {  
    die("Oops! Looks like there was an error on this page. Please go back to the page you were on and try again later.<br />If problems persist please contact us at <a href=\"mailto:".ADMIN_EMAIL."\">".ADMIN_EMAIL."</a>");  
}
```

}

The files `MPDF56/classes/cssmgr.php` and `MPDF56/mpdf.php` keep spitting back `Undefined index` errors, and even though I've added `error_reporting(0);` to the top of both of these pages I keep getting the reports and it's throttling the output of my PDFs and filling my email with about 9000 (that's right, nine thousand) emails each PDF.

Does anyone know how I could disable the error logs for just these pages?? I still want to be getting them for the rest of my site using the custom `set_error_handler()`.

Comment: You're already doing the `$number !== E_NOTICE` check. Why not also do it before sending the mail?

Comment: @mario I'm still wanting them to come through for other parts of my script. :)

Comment: Then check the `$file` as well. Or probe `$number` against the currently active `& error_reporting()` level. See the examples for custom error handlers, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @mario you are a genius! Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks. :D. Post as an answer and I'll mark it. :)